# Fibonacci sequence less than 1000 in R

Tags: r, fibonacci

I'm trying to print the Fibonacci Sequence less than 1000 using while loop in R.

So far,

```
fib <- c(1,1)
counter <-3
while (fib[counter-1]<1000){
  fib[counter]<- fib[counter-2]+fib[counter-1]
  counter = counter+1
}
fib
```

I have this code. Only the first two numbers are given: 1,1. This is printing:

```
1 1 2 3 5 8 13 21 34 55 89 144 233 377 610 987 1597
```

How do I fix my code to print only less than 1000?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Instead of checking the value of the last element wrt 1000, for the expected output you should be checking the sum of the last two elements as so.

```
fib <- c(1,1)
counter <-3
while (fib[counter-2]+fib[counter - 1]<1000){
  fib[counter]<- fib[counter-2]+fib[counter-1]
  counter = counter+1
}
fib
```

Comment: yeah sorry, I just saw that and I guess they posted their answer while I was typing mine out. Haven't really answered anything on here before so what is common etiquette in such a situation? Do I delete the comment?

Comment: Hi Adam, don't worry. Since this is your first answer, I will delete my answer.

Answer (score 1):

The issue with your approach is when the condition (`fib[counter-1]<1000`) in `while` loop is `FALSE` you have already added the number in `fib` which is greater than 1000.

You could return `fib[-length(fib)]` to remove the last number or check the number before inserting the number in `fib`.

```
fib <- c(1,1)
counter <-3

while (TRUE){
  temp <- fib[counter-2] + fib[counter-1]
  if(temp < 1000) 
    fib[counter] <- temp
  else
    break
  counter = counter+1
}
fib
#[1]   1   1   2   3   5   8  13  21  34  55  89 144 233 377 610 987
```

Answer (score 1):

You could change the `while` condition to sum the last 2 answers instead of just the last one:

```r
fib <- c(1,1)
counter <-3
while (sum(fib[counter - 1:2]) < 1000){
    fib[counter]<- fib[counter-2]+fib[counter-1]
    counter = counter+1
}
fib
#>  [1]   1   1   2   3   5   8  13  21  34  55  89 144 233 377 610 987
```

Or just get rid of `counter` completely:

```
fib <- c(1,1) 
while (sum(fib[length(fib) - 0:1]) < 1000) fib <- c(fib, sum(fib[length(fib) - 0:1]))
fib
#>  [1]   1   1   2   3   5   8  13  21  34  55  89 144 233 377 610 987
```